# Передать значения списка в html

Tags: python, html, flask

Существует список `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.
Пытаюсь вывести каждое его значение в таблицу html, но печатается весь список

```
    <table>
{% for i in a %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ a }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

В интернете откапал еще пример с `{%for i in range(0, len)%}` , но тут вообще не понял, что к чему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
<td>{{ a }}</td>
```

Ну, это явная опечатка. Печатать нужно переменную цикла `i`, а не сам список `a`:

```py
<td>{{ i }}</td>
```